# How to create SAP BW as a data source for cognos?

Tags: cognos-10, cognos-bi, sap-bw

I am new to IBM Cognos and I am using Cognos 10 trail version.

I did some of reports using DB2 as a data source. Now I trying to use SAP BW as a data source and I surfed the web and have seen the IBM Cognos guide and in that I went through the steps to connect with SAP BW and when I am doing same using my framework manager I got stuck at 8 step, please have a look into the following link

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRFT_1.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.dyn_query.10.2.1.doc/t_dqm_crt_proj_sap_bw.html

I only have the  following drivers while I am trying to create Data source in it,

Drivers in Cognos:
IBM DB2, IBM Informix Dynamic server, Microsoft SQL server(ODBC), Microsoft SQL server(OLE BC),Microsoft SQL server( 2005 Native client), Microsoft SQL server(2008 Native Client), Microsoft SQL server(2012 Native Client), Microsoft analysis services 2008(ODBO),  Microsoft analysis services 2012(ODBO), Netezza, ODBC, JDBC, Oracle, Progress OpenEdge(ODBC), IBM Red Brick(ODBC), Sysbase Adaptive Server Enterprise(CT-Lib), Sysbase Adaptive Server Enterprise(CT-15),
Teradata, IBM Cognos TM1)

In the 8 step of the above link they tell simply that use type SAP BW as a driver but in my framework manager I did not have the same driver as they said that in the above documentation link. I stuck there, I did not find any solution please tell me solution if any one knows.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add the data source to your Cognos BI Server via. Cognos Administration?
It will then appear in FM as an available data source.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, when I am trying to add SAP BW from Cognos BI Server, there is no option available in BI to create SAP BW as well.

Comment: Hello Scott Campbell do you know how to add SAP BW data source to Cognos

Comment: You can do it within Cognos Administration..?

Comment: Hello Scott Campbell, as i mentioned in the above question I know we can connect with SAP with Cognos through Cognos Administration, but in my Congnos server I have only above mentioned drivers only available, and there is no driver for SAP BW, and thanks to have insterest in this question.